# compactness criterion of a subset of $C(X,F)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $F$ be a Banach space and $X$ a compact metric space. Assume $M \subseteq C(X; F)$

Then I think, I managed to show that $M$ is relatively compact in $C([0,T]; F)$ wrt. to the norm $\sup\limits_{x\in X}\| f \|_F$ if $M$ is equicontinuous at any point $x\in X$ by using the regular Arzela Ascoli theorem for sets in $C([a,b], \mathbb{R})$ ($a<b$).

But I'm not sure if I have made a mistake.

So I wonder if there are any counterexamples maybe to show that I am wrong?

Or is my proof possibly correct?

I know I could post the whole proof here, but I did not want to yet.

Comment: Is $C(X;F)$ the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $F$? I.e., $C(X;F):=\{f: X \to F: \text{$f$ is continuous}\}$?

Comment: @anonymous yes sir

Comment: What’s your notion/definiton for a function being compact?

Comment: @anonymous Sequencially compact. Its equivalent to compactness in normed spaces, no?

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, I thought compactness was a criteria for topological spaces that are sets and not functions.

Comment: Yes, over any metric space sequentially compact is equivalent to compact. And a normed space is automatically a metric space so what you wrote there is correct.

Comment: You just define the metric in the way you define your norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the result is not true. You are missing the boundedness of $M$ (in case $X=\mathbb R$) or the relative compactness of $\{ f(x): \ f\in M\}$
for all $x$ in case $X$ is Banach, see [Arzela-Ascoli @wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces).